# Laravel Form Submission after Authentication

Tags: php, forms, authentication, laravel-5, request

I am developing a form which is public but requires the current user to be logged in before it can be submitted.

Here are my routes:

```
Route::get('exmpleForm', ['as' => 'exmpleForm', 'uses' => 'ExmpleFormController@create']);

/* Routes for form submission. */
Route::group([
    'middleware' => ['auth', 'role:user']
], function() {
    Route::post('exmpleForm', ['as' => 'exmpleForm.store', 'uses' => 'ExmpleFormController@store']);
});
```

**What is happening now:**

When an unauthenticated user submits the form, they are redirected to a login page. After they log in, they are redirected back to the form but it does not submit.

**What I need:**

I need the form to submit with the old data after the user logs in. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if you add this form inside `Route::group` too

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'role:user']], function() {
    Route::get('exmpleForm', .....);
    Route::post('exmpleForm', .....);
});
```

Make's easier to user understand him needs be authenticate before submission form.

Or you can try use Session to put this data form, and get this after user authenticate

```
.session()->put('formData', $data);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/session#basic-usage

Comment: I want to keep the form public to make it available for all visitors to see, so the first option is not a solution. Can you please tell me how to get the form request (or form data) when in the auth controller?

Comment: yes, in app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php

    `public function handle($request....)`
        `dd($request->input());`
..

Answer (score 0):

You need to store data in somewhere(sessions will be ok).

However, the best approach is to use modal dialogs and ajax queries to authenticate user, rather then doing redirects.

Comment: Thanks. I was also thinking similar solution that shows a modal with login options.

Answer (score -1):

Ok. I ran into this, maybe someone can find this fix useful.

Basically, u'll need to store the data in a session when the user is not logged in, and write it to ur persistent storage when the user logs in (or creates an account).

To get form data, create a new middleware that extends Laravel's auth middleware:

```
/**
 * Class FormDataMiddleware
 *
 * @package App\Http\Middleware
 */
class FormDataMiddleware extends Authenticate
{
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * Check if a request is a POST/PATCH and store the request body
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
 * @param  \Closure                 $next
 *
 * @param array                     $guards
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
{
    if (!Auth::check() && !$request->isMethodIdempotent()) {
        Session::put('form-data', [
            'data'  => $request->except(['token']),
        ]);
    }

    return parent::handle($request, $next);
}
```

You can now apply your middleware on an endpoint. Remember to register your middleware in the Kernel file, like so:

```
/**
 * The application's route middleware.
 *
 * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    // Other middleware declarations here
    'form-data'  => \App\Http\Middleware\FormDataMiddleware::class,
];
```

Do not use auth middleware on the same route.

Laravel's default `LoginController` has an `authenticated` function, which is called when a user has successfully authed. This will be the perfect place for your logic. Something like:

```
/**
 * The user has been authenticated.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
 * @param  mixed                    $user
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    if (Session::has('form-data')) {
        $form = Session::pull('form-data');
        // Authorize
        if ($user->can('create', self::class)) {
            // FIXME: Validate data
            $question = $user->questions()->create(array_get($form, 'data'));
            return redirect(route('questions.show', $question));
        }
        // We simply loose the form
    }
}
```

This will work for logins, you need to do the same for new accounts. `RegisterController` also has a function `registered` with identical behavior to `authenticated` method above. Put your code there!